# Is there a shorthand for __host__ and __device__ in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have many functions in my cuda C program with both `__host__` and `__device__` modifiers. I'm looking for a shorthand for these two to make my code look neat by changing

```
__host__ __device__ void foo() {
}
```

to

```
__both__ void foo() {
}
```

.
Of course I can

```
#define __both__ __host__ __device__
```

, but if something like this already existed, I would prefer to use the existing solution.

Comment: nothing like that already exists in the CUDA distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no short hand for this in CUDA C/C++ currently.